# common data between multiple csv in R

Tags: r, csv

I have 10 csv files, each with a single column data (name) entries. For instance, file 1 has 400 entries of names, file 2 has 386 entries of names, file 3 has 700 entries of names and so on.
I want to find the common entries across all 10 csv files and write them onto a new csv file.

It would be great if someone could post a solution, preferably in R.

Comment: after reading all data into R, you can use `intersect` to find which entries are in all CSV files

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  SO is not a free code writing service and what you are asking for is more than 20 lines of code I believe.

Comment: just to get you started: read csv into one "list". then use "reduce" with "intersect".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
your_files           <- c(path1,path2,...)
your_tables          <- lapply(your_files,read.csv)
your_common_colnames <- Reduce(intersect,lapply(your_tables,colnames))
your_new_tables      <- lapply(your_tables,`[`,your_common_colnames)
your_output          <- do.call(rbind,your_new_tables)
```

**Example :**

```
mtcars1 <- mtcars[1:3,1:5]
#                mpg cyl disp  hp drat
# Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110 3.90
# Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90
# Datsun 710    22.8   4  108  93 3.85
mtcars2 <- mtcars[1:3,3:10]
#               disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear
# Mazda RX4      160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4
# Datsun 710     108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4
your_tables          <- list(mtcars1,mtcars2)
your_common_colnames <- Reduce(intersect,lapply(your_tables,colnames))
your_new_tables      <- lapply(your_tables,`[`,your_common_colnames)
your_output          <- do.call(rbind,your_new_tables)
#                disp  hp drat
# Mazda RX4       160 110 3.90
# Mazda RX4 Wag   160 110 3.90
# Datsun 710      108  93 3.85
# Mazda RX41      160 110 3.90
# Mazda RX4 Wag1  160 110 3.90
# Datsun 7101     108  93 3.85
```

Comment: Thanks Acarbalacar, Andre Elrico and Moody_Mudskipper for pointing me in the right direction and the solution.

Comment: Thanks Tim Biegeleisen for the rhetoric.

Comment: You're welcome, consider validating the answer (green tick mark on the left) if it solved your issue